# Connection refused for connecting with MySQL server using php in XAMPP(MacOS)

Tags: php, mysql, database, macos, xampp

I am new to database. I was trying to connect mysql server with php code. But I don't know why I am getting error for connection.(I tried in windows changing the "localhost:8080" to "localhost" and it worked perfectly.)

**MyCode:**

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost:8080","root","","test1");

if($link === false){
    die("Error: Could not connect. ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

**Refused Warning:**
[image]

**XAMPP Port:**
[image]

Comment: Use localhost same here no ?

Comment: Tried with IP address 192.168.64.2. But same error

Comment: All service are run ?

Comment: Yes, all service are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localhost:8080` is for you web server. If your MySQL server runs on default settings, use port 3306. `localhost:3306`.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","root","","test1");
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Struggled for half day……  I used XAMPP 8 and connection to MySQL keep refuesed(errno 61). Actually XAMPP install MySQL in VM, so connect it via IP address show in XAMPP. There is no MySQL server on localhost.
[image]

Change localhost to XAMPP IP address work for me.

```
db = pymysql.connect(host="192.168.64.2", port=3306, user="test", password='test', db="test")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change localhost to 127.0.0.1

I spent a day trying to solve it. `mysqli` was giving error with localhost.